# git status for a past commit?

Tags: git, version-control, commit, git-status

how to do a `git status` to view changed files in a past commit?

NOTE: this question might have already been asked, but phrased much differently. however, I am astounded to see that searching for the following expression on Google yields no useful results: `git status for past commit`.

Comment: What information do you want to retrieve from said `git status for past commit`?

Comment: `git status` isn’t used on a commit, so that might be why you’re getting no results. Are you looking for `git show [--stat] <commit>`?

Comment: `git status` tells you about the state of your *working tree*.  What would that mean for a commit?

Comment: To expand slightly on @OliverCharlesworth comment, `git status` prints: (1) information about the current branch (and vs its upstream if set); (2) the state of any in-progress rebase, merge, etc., in the work-tree; and (3) the result of comparing `HEAD` to the index and the index to the work-tree, if you are not in the middle of a merge. Only part of (3) involves an existing commit and then *if and only if* you are not still merging.

Comment: `git status` for past commits is spelled either `git log` or `git show`.

Comment: What I want is to show is roughly what would have a `git status` shown in the past before adding and committing files, for that given commit. To sum up, I wanted to see which files changed with a commit (and I am uninterested in files which have simply not been added nor removed).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found:

`git show --stat --oneline b8351c4`

Where `b8351c4` is the regarded commit.

Answer (score 29):

`git show --name-status <commit>`

Answer (score 6):

`git status` is the wrong command here. If you want to see what a previous commit did you should use `git show <commit>`.